# Looking for a Jubula hack / alternative which makes identifying components using XPATH possible

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, jubula

We have plans to use Jubula to test the functionality of our web application but after evaluating Jubula we have run into a problem. We can't make Jubula click fields which have a varying id (generated).

I know that Jubula uses Selenium inside so using XPATH for maching elements in the DOM should not be a problem. Do you know about any Jubula hack or alternative / derivative which makes this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not that easy to use XPATH directly with Jubula. However, Jubula uses XPATH internally to address components in a web page.

Your problem might be solvable by just ignoring the id's and using context and hierarchy for component mapping. To do this just try setting the names weight to zero in the object mapping editor (on the Configuration View). You may have to adjust the Threshold slider as well.

Comment: This does not help me. Do you have any other ideas?